My vehicle will start normally. Then doesnt.why?
05 ford escape. The car will turn on normally in the morning for work. And normally when i leave. But if i turn it on and stop by the gas station for about 5 minutes. The car just refuses to start. The battery will run power to my lights, radio, and all that, but turning the key makes zero noise. Every light on the board is on when this happens. Then after a little while. Itll turn on like nothing happen

When you do a normal drive, say, to work, and you stop the car and take the key out of the ignition, is the key warm or hot? Or just normal ambient temperature?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
